# __ in Ocaml extracted from Coq

Tags: ocaml, coq

Ocaml code extracted from Coq includes (in some cases) a type `__` and a function `__` defined as follows:

```
type __ = Obj.t
let __ = let rec f _ = Obj.repr f in Obj.repr f
```

The documentation says that in the past, such type was defined as `unit` (and thus `__` could be taken as `()`) but there exist (rare) cases where a value of type `__` is applied to a value of type `__`.

`__` uses undocumented functions of the `Obj` module from OCaml, but it seems that what is defined is essentially a totally polymorphic function that eats all its arguments (whatever their number).

Is there some documentation regarding the cases where `__` cannot be eliminated and values of this type are applied to values of the same type, both from a theoretical (construct Coq terms where elimination is impossible) and from a practical (show a realistic case where this occurs) point of view?

Answer (score 4):

The references cited in the [README](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/7d220f8b61649646692983872626d6a8042446a9/plugins/extraction/README) give a nice overview of the erasure problem. Specifically, both [this](https://www.irif.fr/%7Eletouzey/download/rapport_dea.ps.gz) report and [this](https://www.irif.fr/%7Eletouzey/download/extraction2002.pdf) article exaplain in detail how the type schemes and logical parts of CIC terms are erased, and why one must have `__ x = __`. The problem is not exactly that `__` may be applied to itself, but that it may be applied to *anything at all*.

Unfortunately, it is not at all clear if having this behavior is important in any non-pathological case. The motivation given there is to be able to extract *any* Coq term, and the documents do not mention any cases that are really interesting from a practical standpoint. The example given on [3](https://www.irif.fr/%7Eletouzey/download/extraction2002.pdf) is this one:

```
Definition foo (X : Type) (f : nat -> X) (g : X -> nat) := g (f 0).
Definition bar := foo True (fun _ => I).
```

Executing `Recursive Extraction bar.` gives the following result:

```
type __ = Obj.t
let __ = let rec f _ = Obj.repr f in Obj.repr f

type nat =
| O
| S of nat

(** val foo : (nat -> 'a1) -> ('a1 -> nat) -> nat **)

let foo f g =
  g (f O)

(** val bar : (__ -> nat) -> nat **)

let bar =
  foo (Obj.magic __)
```

Since `foo` is polymorphic on `Type`, there is no way of simplifying the `f O` application on its body, because it could have computational content. However, since `Prop` is a subtype of `Type`, `foo` can also be applied to `True`, which is what happens in `bar`. When we try to reduce `bar`, thus, we will have `__` being applied to `O`.

This particular case is not very interesting, because it would be possible to fully inline `foo`:

```
let bar g =
  g __
```

Since `True` can't be applied to anything, if `g` corresponds to any legal Coq term, its `__` argument also wouldn't be applied to anything, and therefore it would be safe to have `__ = ()` (I believe). However, there are cases where it is not possible to know in advance whether an erased term can be further applied or not, which makes the general definition for `__` necessary. Check out for instance the `Fun` example [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/7d220f8b61649646692983872626d6a8042446a9/test-suite/success/extraction.v), near the end of the file.